# how to convert dictionary to list in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like this.

```
dict = {'cow': [200, 50], 'chicken': [100, 70], 'pig': [300, 20]}
```

I want to convert this dictionary to list with this result.

```
list = [['cow', 200, 50], ['chicken', 100, 70], ['pig', 300, 20]]
```

I really tried to find how to do it but failed.

Comment: Where's your code? Have you attempted something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the one-liner:

```
a = [[k, *v] for k,v in d.items()]
```

<sub>(Never name anything `list` or `dict`.)</sub>

Comment: In higher versions of Python 3: `[[k, *v] for k,v in d.items()]`

Comment: It wasn't meant a correction. More of an elaboration.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know, but it is a better way to do it.